# Effect of parasitic capacitance on an ideal signal?

Tags: driver, signal, digital-logic, capacitance

How does parasitic capacitance affect an ideal signal?

Ie. We have an ideal signal shown below, what would it look like with parasitic capacitance accounted for?

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is an example of what happens, not intended to be overly realistic but to simply provide a visual.  Actual effects can vary quite a bit depending on the circuit and where the parasitic capacitance is as well as how its interacting with other components.

In short this is a heavily simplified example for illustration purposes only.

Test Setup:

[image]

A 1us duration 1V square pulse with 1ns rise and fall time is generated, i've added 5 ohm of output impedance to the source and the values of R3 and L1 should be ballpark reasonable for a 5cm PCB trace.  C1 is representative of parasitic capacitance on the trace / from the receiving end.  Load was randomly chosen to be 1k ohm.

Then we do a transient analysis (time) from 0 to 3us and check the response with 5 values of C1 from 10pF to 100nF.  Ultimately these values are high for this given situation but it will more easily let you see the effects.

[image]

And here is the response at Vout.  The most square of the bunch is with C1 = 10pF and the most rounded C1 = 100nF.  You can also see the ringing caused by the interaction of the parasitic inductance (L1).

In the general case additional parasitic capacitance creates a low pass filter when combined with the resistances present.

This causes the signal's rise and fall times to becomes longer as C1 takes longer to charge and discharge.

In reality changes in parasitic capacitance can have a number of different effects depending on their interaction with inductances and other factors.

Here is another example of what can happen, same test setup just zoomed in on the rising edge and showing C1 = 10pF and C1 = 50pF.  While the rise time is longer with 50pF the real issue is the massive increase in ringing caused by the interaction with L1.

[image]

Comment: What sim software are you using?

Comment: @Fake Name Qucs, I don't use it for complex stuff so can't speak to its capabilities in that regard but find it great to use for simple stuff like this.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing affects a ideal signal.  If it did, it wouldn't be ideal anymore.

Basically, parasitic capacitance is a small distributed capacitance to ground.  For traces on a normal board, the stray capacitance will be from a few pF to a few 10s of pF depending on the trace length and how close it is to the ground plane and other traces.  There is nothing magic about this capacitance.  Together with the signal's impedance, it will cause a low pass filter, just like a deliberate capacitance to ground would.

For example, let's say a digital signal has 100 Ω impedance and 10 pF stray capacitance to ground.  At first approximation that will cause a low pass filter with 160 MHz rolloff.  So if the signals you care about, including their harmonics you care about, are limited to 100 MHz or so, there should be little issue.

Another way to look at the same thing is to consider the time constant.  100Ω x 10pF = 1ns, so the 80% settling time of a single digital edge will be 1.6 ns, and the 90% settling time 2.3 ns.

Comment: I enjoyed the ideal signal comment. It might be worth noting for those that do not understand the affects of a low-pass filter it just makes the transitions slow, as an Ideal square waves has frequencies to infinity it will clip off the higher ones and you will get a slower transition.